# mongoose query to find based on multiple not equals

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i am trying to get results from my `userId` such that both `type != 4` and `userType != 1`

i tried :

```
const transaction = {
    userId: userId,
    $and: [{ type: { $ne: 4 } }, { userType: { $ne: 1 } }]
  };
await.Transactions.find(transaction)
```

but this is giving me empty set.

the below is a snippet of my db data

```
id: 5ed8dfb1b6c73a69b0adca7d
amount: 150
userId: 5ed5c7fdc25ee07e41a502af
type: 4
userType: 1
recipientId: 5ed8d3a36b34b55f66f62fcd
status:"succeeded"

_id: 5ed987747833b724d9f31829
amount: 1000
userId: 5ed8d3a36b34b55f66f62fcd
type: 4
userType: 2
ChargeId: "tr_1GqSjvKYps1wFgvm0thxzh0p"
ChargeObject: "transfer"
status: "pending"
__v: 0

_id: 5ed987747833b724d9f31841
amount: 1000
userId: 5ed8d3a36b34b55f66f62fcd
type: 3
userType: 1
ChargeId: "ch_1GqSjvKYps1wFgvm0thxzh0p"
ChargeObject: "charge"
status: "pending"
__v: 0
```

Comment: Did you check if type of input variable `userId` matches with field `userId` in document ? If field `userId` is of type `ObjectId()` then you need to convert input string to `ObjectId()` just take the input from code & run the query directly on DB & check the output..

Comment: That criteria will exclude all of the documents in your sample, each one has either type:4 or userType:1, so none with match both inequalities at the same time.

Comment: yeah.. i think that is waht happening... what would be the correct criteria??

Answer (score 0):

based on your criteria, it should be like:

```
{ $and:[ {userId: userId},{ type: { $ne: 4 } }, { userType: { $ne: 1 } } ] }
```

Comment: im not sure why there are 2 documents that have the same document id "_ID" tho : 5ed987747833b724d9f31829

Comment: yeah, i just forgot to edit the id number.. fixed!!
but the query u gave won't work in my case, i basically want to exclude the documents which have both `type != 4` and `userType != 1`. so it might be like getting the documents with `type==4` and `userType == 1` and then excluding that set from the whole set...

Comment: if I understand it properly, you want to get documents which match the userId, AND type NOT EQUAL to 4, AND userType NOT EQUAL to 1 ?

Comment: in your given DB items/example, no document seem to match those criteria, so im expecting and empty result

Comment: i want to get documents with user id which don't have  type NOT EQUAL to 4, AND userType NOT EQUAL to 1 in single document... 
if a particular user has  type NOT EQUAL to 4 and userType EQUAL to 2, it will be selected

Answer (score 0):

The criteria are `type != 4` and `userType != 1`, if you want exclude documents for which both of these are true, this statement will be true for documents you want to match:

```
not(and(type != 4, userType != 1 ))
```

That seems to be some excessive negation, the above is logically equivalent to:

```
or(type = 4, userType = 1)
```

In MQL:

```
{userId: userId, $or:[ {type: 4}, {userType: 1} ]}
```

Comment: is `{userId: userId, $or:[ {type: 4}, {userType: 1} ]}` your proposed solution?
i didn't get it..